# Не могу установить программу на FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

Подскажите, вылетает какая-то ошибка при установке программ. Устанавливал sendmail, знаю, что он уже встроен, но пробовал с dovecot - та же проблема. Я еще не совсем разобрался с FreeBSD, может я что-то не так делаю.

Дерево портов обновлено.

Версия ОС FreeBSD8.1

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, если вы "ещё не совсем разобрались с FreeBSD", то каким чудом вас занесло в такое старое 8.1?

Comment: Было задание от преподавателя - собрать почтовый сервер.
Попросил сделать это на старых версиях 6-7.х, ибо у него там что-то настроено. Я, если честно, разницу увидел между 8 и 10.х только в изменениях некоторого синтаксиса, потому что дальше я не забирался, и в подробности сильно не вдавался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD 8 уже не поддерживается, поэтому новое дерево портов на ней не соберется. Можете попробовать взять старую ревизию дерева портов, которое еще поддерживало 8 фряху. Либо обновить систему хотя бы до 10.4.